# Paso de parámetros entre fragments en Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

en esta ocasión estoy tratando de pasar parámetros entre Fragmentos y por lo que he leído esto no es posible sin el uso de Interfaces, por lo que he realizado la implementación de dicha interfaz y el código correspondiente en el fragmento A y el fragmento B.

**Interfaz**

```
public interface EnviarCategoria {
    public void enviarDatos(Categoria categoria);
}
```

**Escritorio Fragment (recoge datos y envía a fragmento B)**

```
public class EscritorioFragment extends Fragment {
    EnviarCategoria enviarCategoria;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        adaptador.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                        "Ha seleccionado la categoria: "+listaCategorias.get(recyclerListaCategorias.getChildAdapterPosition(v)).getId(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // envia los datos de la categoria al fragmento
                enviarCategoria.enviarDatos(listaCategorias.get(recyclerListaCategorias.getChildAdapterPosition(v)));
            }
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return vista;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;

        enviarCategoria = (EnviarCategoria) context; // comunica con la interfaz
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
```

**Fragmento B - recibe los datos**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_productos_categoria, container, false);
    categoriaRecibida = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.categoriaRecibidaTV);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return vista;
}

public void recibirDatos(Categoria categoriaRecibidaObj){
    categoriaRecibida.setText(categoriaRecibidaObj.getNombre());
}
```

**Home Activity - comunicación entre fragments**

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements EnviarCategoria{
    Fragment miFragmento = null;
    @Override
    public void enviarDatos(Categoria categoria) {
        ProductosCategoriaFragment myfragment = (ProductosCategoriaFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.productoCategoriaFragment);
        myfragment.recibirDatos(categoria);
        miFragmento = new ProductosCategoriaFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,miFragmento).commit();
    }
}
```

Pero al momento de ejecutar el click la aplicación se paraliza, ¿Qué es lo que me está faltando? o ¿alguna sugerencia al respecto?, agradezco su ayuda.

**El Error del logcat**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.drunkliquor.pedidos.fragmentos.ProductosCategoriaFragment.recibirDatos(com.drunkliquor.pedidos.modelos.Categoria)' on a null object reference
    at com.drunkliquor.pedidos.HomeActivity.enviarDatos(HomeActivity.java:149)
    at com.drunkliquor.pedidos.fragmentos.EscritorioFragment$2.onClick(EscritorioFragment.java:130)
    at com.drunkliquor.pedidos.adaptadores.AdaptadorCategorias.onClick(AdaptadorCategorias.java:80)
```

Comment: deberías mostrar el error que te aparece

Comment: Tienes razón @Luis lo he agregado al error ahora, gracias por la observación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que tu fragment `ProductosCategoriaFragment` aun no se muestra cuando quieres mandar los datos. En la parte donde haces `myfragment = (ProductosCategoriaFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()`, puede que estes o no mostrando el fragment (depende del numero de fragments que tengas en pantalla). Si solo estas mostrando un fragment a la vez, el `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById()` te va a devolver un `null`. Por ultimo, `miFragmento` es el `fragment` que quieres mostrar y lo agregas con una transaccion. Ese `fragment` es el que tienes que utilizar para recibir tus datos.

```
public void enviarDatos(Categoria categoria) {
    miFragmento = new ProductosCategoriaFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,miFragmento).commit();
    miFragmento.recibirDatos(categoria);
}
```

Comment: Gracias @Yorch por tu comentario, efectivamente tengo un activity y dos fragment por separado, cada uno con su propio layout y si ProductosCategoriaFragment es en donde se recibe los datos y lleva implementado un método para recibir los datos como indica en la redacción de la pregunta. Entonces la pregunta sería ¿Cómo se resolvería en este caso?, ¿alguna sugerencia?

Comment: pense que con lo que puse de codigo quedaria bien jeje, es que en tu funcion enviardatos, tu primera linea buscas un fragment que no esta desplegado (por eso falla la aplicacion), y luego 2 lineas mas abajo creas una instancia de tu fragment, asi que yo en mi codigo sugeri quitar ese findFragmentById

Comment: Que vaina, apenas lo vengo a ver!!, ahora la pregunta es que es mejor comunicar los fragments con interfaces o bundle?

Comment: acabo de hacer los cambios que has sugerido, pero salto otro error que fue que en el momento que el fragment que recibe los datos los hace en una función recibedatos donde le asignaba directamente al control el valor que recibe, así que eso ha sido cambiado y asignado a una variable del mismo tipo que se recibe para luego ser asignado en el createview al control. Problema resuelto gracias a ti.

Comment: me alegra que ya te funcionara, respondiendo a tu pregunta de que es mejor si con una interfaz o con un bundle, te puedo decir que las 2 formas funcionan pero yo lo que suelo hacer (de manera personal), cuando tienes que mostrar 2 fragments al mismo tiempo (ejemplo, una lista a la izquierda y detalles a la derecha) uso interfaces, cuando solo muestro un fragment a la vez, suelo utilizar bundles

Comment: Y de las dos maneras me conserva la característica realtime que tiene firebase por ejemplo?

Comment: eso depende mas de tu implementacion y no es que tenga que ver con si son fragments o no

Comment: Gracias por la dirección!..

Answer (score 1):

Veo que has arreglado el error, pero igual vale la pena dejar este comentario.

Si se puede enviar informacion entre fragmentos sin necesidad de una interfaz. El envio de informacion entre fragmentos se realiza de la siguiente forma

```
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
Bundle data = new Bundle();
data.putInt('int1', 1);
data.putString('String2', "Foo");
fragment.setArguments(data)
```

Y luego dentro del onCreate de MyFragment

```
Bundle data = this.getArguments();
if(data != null){
    Int int1 = data.getInt('int1');
    String string2 = data.getString('String2');
}
```

Comment: Gracias @Mauro, la pregunta es si es mejor usar un Bundle, esto me garantizaría que si hay cambios sobre los datos seleccionados por el usuario, estos se reflejen en tiempo real para el usuario?